# How to fix issue in wordpress/woocommerce that only impacts certain products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

After changing website domain this issue with page margins has started to appear on certain pages. (might not be page margins looking for some direction)
I've tried checking standard things like uninstalling plugins etc and have come to the conclusion its something to do with the theme. We are using a child theme but in regards to php my knowledge is VERY limited.

see example;
https://blueskyeventhire.com/categories/catering-equipment-hire/jack-stack-104-plate/

Comment: _"see example"_ - no; see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `opacity: 0;` on the component on the left side. That is not a margin.

[image]

Comment: Okay so any idea why the issue is happening?